# What kind of creme could Ueli Steck be possibly using and why?

Tags: gear, health, walking

Watching this [youtube-video](https://youtu.be/5jLCeSSIF-k?t=98) I asked myself if Ueli Steck is using some kind of regeneration creme.

Most likely nobody will know for sure from the footage but I would be really interested what tricks the experts like Steck have for enhancing the regeneration.

Related: [How can I recuperate between two long walks](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10579/how-can-i-recuperate-between-two-long-walks/10583#10583)

Comment: You *could* just try and ask him... Maybe he'll happily help out other outdoorsmen? :) http://www.uelisteck.ch/en/contact.html

Comment: @fgysin Good idea, I'll do that :)

Comment: Did you ever come around to ask? I'd be interested to know. :)

Comment: @fgysin Thx for the reminder ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked Ueli Steck as @fgysin suggested and got the following answer:

```
It is "Sportusal Spray". This is a spray stimulating the blood flow.
```

For more information have a look at the medication here:

http://www.medicatione.com/?c=drug&s=sportusal%20spray%20sine%20heparino

Comment: Hi Wills! I don't want to write a conflicting answer because you spoke directly to the company, but they only told you part of the story. As we can see on the linked page, more than anything, it's a pain-relieving and body soothing med. It's one of the reasons athletes use it. The main ingredient, DMSO, is a pain reliever that was developed in the 1950s. My dad was a doctor on that original team, and we used it when we were kids. Do you want me to write an answer based on what it says on that web page, and others, or would you prefer I leave this alone?

Comment: Hi @Sue. Of course you are welcomed to write an answer especially when you have those deep inside informations. :)